# LOVE NOKIA / NOKIA LOVE makes sense?

Tags: phrases, sentence-meaning

I'm making a simply typography design which would either say LOVE NOKIA or NOKIA LOVE.

I want to use one of them to convey : I love Nokia / We love Nokia / We all love Nokia.

But for some reasons I can't use I/We/We all.

So any of LOVE NOKIA / NOKIA LOVE can convey same meaning? Or these seem grammatically incorrect?

PS: Nokia is a tech/communication company/brand.

Comment: We've heard of Nokia.

Comment: It's for people who would comment "We haven't heard of Nokia".

Comment: What planet would they live on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“*Love Nokia*” has the feel of “{omitted subject such as *I*, *we* , *you*} *love Nokia*” or of an imperative telling the reader to love Nokia. There is therefore a feeling of personal involvement on the part of the reader.

“*Nokia love*” has the structure of a noun phrase where Nokia is an adjective. Or perhaps an unfinished sentence “*Nokia love ...*” which has no implied object and in which there is confusion as to whether Nokia is a singular ("*Nokia loves ..."*) or plural (*"Nokia love..."*) entity. None of these feelings relates to a reader in a personal way.

In consequence, the first has more emotional force and I suggest it is better. Neither is grammatically attractive but, in such a constrained design, this is secondary to the requirement for emotional impact.

Comment: Nokia love could be a form of love, and could have a salacious meaning. I once heard of a fetish magazine called "Glove Love".

Comment: I should make it clear that I neither owned any copies of the magazine, nor did I have a hand in its production.